# Text is exceeding the DIV style width

Tags: html, css, css-float, inline

What I am trying to do is write to a new document taking input from the HTML through JS. The example I am posting is aimed at fixing the issue of a div overflow. Within the second div (column 2 if you will), I have styled inline width of 100px and given it a word-wrap:word-break that is working for the width of the page, but not the width of the div. Please advise on how I can fix it to work on the width of the div.

I have tried floating it. Another thing I am unclear on is whether the next line is affecting it. Does the next line need a float/clear? I am providing the following line as well (that is not styled in this format)

```
myText += ("<div style='float:left; width=100px; padding:10px'>"+ "CAREER OBJECTIVES"+ "</div>"+ "<div style='width=100px; padding:10px; word-wrap:break-word'>"+objectives+"</div>"+"<br><br>");
myText += ("PERSONAL DATA" + "<p align='right'><textarea rows='3' cols='50'>"+personalInfo+"</textarea></p>"+"<br><br>");
```

I wanted to have the appearance of "columns" the second div should be to the right of the first. The "personal data" line should be the beginning of the new "column" on the left side.
Thank you.

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute has been obsolete for a number of years now.

Comment: Might I suggest using CSS column-count property for creating multiple columns? You just need to place everything in one div and specify how many columns you want. It's support by all the major browsers. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: interesting. But how would I insert text into a specific column?

Comment: Well you cant place at specific columns using the column-count property.why dont you create a flex container with 2 divs inside (side by side) and fill them via your js appropriately.

Comment: You have errors - `width=100px` instead of `width:100px` - that prevent the divs from producing the columns you want.